# Space after if, while, etc (and before the paren)

Tags: coding-style

Most coding conventions prefer putting a space after `if`, `while`, etc (`if (` vs `if(`). Is there a particular reason for this, or is that something that is a personal quirk?

Comment: What about languages that don't use brackets?

Answer (score 80):

I always thought that it was in order to differentiate them from function calls.

Comment: +1 This is true for the JavaScript, Java, C family which use parens both in structured statements and function calls.  To quote Douglas Crockford's [JavaScript coding conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html): "A blank space should not be used between a function value and its ( (left parenthesis). This helps to distinguish between keywords and function invocations."

Comment: Also, to quote the [Linux kernel style guide](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle): "Linux kernel style for use of spaces depends (mostly) on function-versus-keyword usage.  Use a space after (most) keywords.  The notable exceptions are sizeof, typeof, alignof, and \_\_attribute\_\_, which look somewhat like functions."

Comment: If it's a keyword, it shouldn't have parentheses. If a language structure requires parentheses, if shouldn't have a space. Just my opinion, but I find the space makes it *less* readable.

Comment: it doesn't really affect readability for me, but it does make the iff look like a method call for a moment. I tend to put the space in out of habit. I work in several languages that don't use a brace to start a block.

Comment: if(foo) (without space) looks like a function, which is always annoying.

Comment: I prefer without a space for the very reason that it looks like a function call. To me it seems more consistent, and we needn't worry about confusing the two due to modern syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

It's very subjective question, but there are code conventions. Example in Java:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-whitespace.html

"Blank spaces should be used in the following circumstances: ...A keyword followed by a parenthesis..."

`while (`

or

`for (`

But with modern IDEs it's not a critical question anymore, in my opinion.

I prefer NOT to add a space in these cases (after keywords like `for`, but in function/method calls `function()` as well.
I think, `function ()` is less readable.